# How to specify the relative path to the workbook in the LINK field?

Tags: excel, ms-word, word-field

After a Paste special linking of a range of cells from Excel to Word (2013) the field looks like this:

`{ LINK Excel.Sheet.12 "D:\\RelativePath\\1\\work\\tmp.xlsx" Sheet1!NamedRange \a \p }`

If you move the source (.xlsx) and receiver (.docx) to the 2 folder, you need to change the link in the LINK field so that it looks like this:

`{ LINK Excel.Sheet.12 "D:\\RelativePath\\2\\work\\tmp.xlsx" Sheet1!NamedRange \a \p }`

When there are many such fields, it is inconvenient.

I tried both this:

`{ LINK Excel.Sheet.12 "...\\...\\work\\tmp.xlsx" Sheet1!NamedRange \a \p }`

and that:

`{ LINK Excel.Sheet.12 "~\\work\\tmp.xlsx" Sheet1!NamedRange \a \p }`
but nothing works.

That doesn't work either:

[How to create absolute hyperlinks and relative hyperlinks in Word documents](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/903163/how-to-create-absolute-hyperlinks-and-relative-hyperlinks-in-word-docu)

Is it possible to specify in the LINK field not absolute, but relative source address?

**Upd** @Cindy Meister suggested a solution and after some refinement the code works fine.

Here he is:

```
Sub updateLINKs()
Dim doc As Word.Document
Dim fld As Word.Field
Dim sFilePath As String, sFileName As String
Set doc = ActiveDocument
sFilePath = doc.Path
For Each fld In doc.Fields
    If fld.Type = wdFieldLink Then
      If fld.Result.InlineShapes.Count > 0 And _
         InStr(fld.OLEFormat.ClassType, "Excel") And _
         fld.LinkFormat.SourcePath <> sFilePath Then
           sFileName = fld.LinkFormat.SourceName
           fld.LinkFormat.SourceFullName = sFilePath & "\" & sFileName
      End If
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to use relative paths in `Link` fields. The path needs to be updated/changed in the field code. This can be done in a reasonably straight-forward manner by using the possibilities provided by the `LinkFormat` property.

For example, assuming the relative path would be the same path as the Word document the following code:

1. Gets the path from the `Document.Path` property
2. Loops all the fields in the document and determines whether they're a LINK field from an Excel source that displays an `InlineShape` (an object, rather than text). The fields are looped in reverse order, since changing the path causes Word to delete and recreate the LINK in the background. This means a loop from the beginning of the document will repeatedly "hit" the same field, resulting in an endless loop.
3. Determines the current file name for the linked object from the `Link` field using `LinkFormat.SourceName`
4. Concatenates the information and assigns it to the `LinkFormat.SourceFullName` property

Note that the `LinkFormat.SourcePath` and `LinkFormat.SourceName` properties are read-only, so the path can only be changed using `SourceFullName`.

```
Sub UpdateLinks()
    Dim doc As Word.Document
    Dim fld As Word.Field, nrFields As Long, i As Long
    Dim sFilePath As String, sFileName As String

    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    sFilePath = doc.path
    nrFields = doc.Fields.Count
    For i = nrFields To 1 Step -1
        Set fld = doc.Fields(i)
        If fld.Type = wdFieldLink Then
          If fld.result.InlineShapes.Count > 0 And _
             InStr(fld.OleFormat.ClassType, "Excel") Then
               sFileName = fld.LinkFormat.SourceName
               fld.LinkFormat.SourceFullName = sFilePath & "\" & sFileName
          End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for opening .SourceFullName for me, explaining read-only .SourcePath and .SourceName, otherwise I was about to use a search with replacement.
I have a compiler swearing at If without Then, so added Then.
Also replaced "> 1" with "> 0", as the user can move files when he has only one LINK added.
In this case, an infinite loop occurs. Perhaps, it is necessary to use not ">", but ForEach?

Comment: The `And` added an additional check to the `If` - `Then` does not belong at the end of the first line. But the `_` is required to extend the `If` to a second line - perhaps you left that out. Yes, `>0` would actually be correct (sorry!) This code is only a sample, to provide a starting point. It's not meant to be the final solution as we cannot know *exactly* how you need to use it. Some parts you may not need, there may be some things you'd need in addition. The main purpose is to demonstrate what's possible so that you can integrate/extend it - not to give you a final solution.

Comment: Here is a [screenshot](https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2018/12/31/88794b1a03db2a8a878858c173bb7345-full.png).
Compiler swears on the line `If fld.Type = wdFieldLink` and wants `Then`. After adding `Then` an infinite loop occurs.

Comment: Ah, *there*. The edit you'd made was in the next line, after the `And`. Yes, of course a `Then` is needed in that line - my apologies. I've corrected the example.

Comment: happy new year!
Yes, now everything is fine with `Then`, but the endless cycle remains.
And this is natural, since the code does not check whether LINK has changed.
I think we need to add one more variable - `newPath` and another `If`. It will start the subsequent chain of operators only if `oldPath` is not equal to `newPath`, otherwise it will exit.

Comment: @BorisBaublys Ah, yes, I didn't think about Word's destroying and recreating the LINK field in the background, due to the changed path. I've corrected the code and the explanation. Again, my apologies!

Answer (score 1):

You *cannot* specify a relative path in a LINK field. That would require embedding another field in the LINK field but, as I've said previously, you can't do that with LINK fields. The link you posted concerns only the setting of a hyperlink base for hyperlinks, which also doesn't result in a truly relative link.

The only workaround for a LINK field is to use a macro that updates the absolute path.

Comment: Thanks but sadly. It is not clear why the developers did not foresee this moment. 

OK, then VBA. I see an algorithm like this: 

a) Reading the path to ThisWorkbook. 

b) Reading the name ThisWorkbook. 

c) Constructing a new full path (path + name) 

d) Reading text between the third and fourth space. 

e) Replacing links in a loop. 

Are there any unobvious obstacles?

Is there something like a ThisWorkbook in the Word?

Comment: For a macro to implement relative paths in Word, check out macro attached to:
http://www.msofficeforums.com/word/38722-word-fields-relative-paths-external-files.html or https://forums.windowssecrets.com/showthread.php/154379-Word-Fields-and-Relative-Paths-to-External-Files. Note that the macro takes the same approach for all external links, even though the thread describes other methods for INCLUDETEXT fields, etc.

Comment: thank you.
Your code uses a replacement search. It seems to me that .SourceFullName is more efficient and the code is shorter.
But the main thing is that the code should solve the problem. If a search with a replacement solves, then that's good. I have not yet been able to test it, since registration is required for downloading.

Could you put the code adapted for this task here?

Comment: My code uses a replacement approach since it isn't merely assuming the new folder is the same folder as the code is being run from (i.e. the required folder might be a different one but always in a relative location to the current one). I don't propose to 'adapt' the code.